# java enum option without index

Tags: java, enums, enumerator

I want to define an enumerator that can accept specific values but also provides something like a `default`-option called `CUSTOM` with which I can set the index of the enumerator to any integer.

This is my first try:

```
public enum EnumClass {
    CUSTOM(),
    NONE(0),
    OPTION1(-1),
    OPTION2(-2);

    private int value;
    private EnumClass (int value) { this.value = value; }
    private EnumClass () {}
    public static EnumClass Custom(int value) {
        if (-2 <= value && value <= 0) return EnumClass.valueOf(value);
        EnumClass result = EnumClass.CUSTOM;
        result.value = value;
        return result;
    }

    public int getValue() { return value; }
}
```

My problems with this solution are:

- `value` would normally be `final` but I need to be not final to make the option `CUSTOM` working.
- I get a runtime error everytime I try to create EnumClass-instances with values like -5 or even with -2. (Apparently my compiler goes crazy because after I tried putting in -5 I tried -2 but it still tells me that -5 is a out of bounds.)
- As there are so many problems: Is this even useful concept?

Comment: There is only one single instance of `EnumClass.CUSTOM` so each time you call `Custom(int value)` the value will change for all existing references.  I don't think this is what you intend.  You seem to be asking for a dynamically updateable enum, which does not exist in Java.  You can of course write your own class from scratch to do this.

Comment: You cannot create new instances of enum values. Enums are very fixed, e.g. your example has exactly 4 instances and that cannot be changed at runtime. Use a regular class if you need to add extra instances.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think using `enum` in this situation is correct. If you look at the oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

> An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants.

Values have to be **predefined**. Your example tries to do set values runtime. In your case it is probably better to use `classes` instead of `enums`. A factory would probably help here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove CUSTOM  and instead use a separate class that holds custom values. Then add a common interface that both your Custom class and your Enum class implement. E.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HasValue hv = HasValue.get(-2);
    System.out.println(hv);
}

public interface HasValue {
    static HasValue get(int value) {
        for (EnumClass el : EnumClass.values()) {
            if (el.value == value) {
                return el;
            }
        }

        return new Custom(value);
    }

    int value();

    class Custom implements HasValue {
        private final int value;

        Custom(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public int value() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    enum EnumClass implements HasValue {
        NONE(0),
        OPTION1(-1),
        OPTION2(-2);

        private final Integer value;

        private EnumClass (int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        private EnumClass () {
            value = null;
        }

        @Override
        public int value() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```